# How to get scrolling content in a master page, that's in an iFrame?

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

Sorry, I know that's a really bad title, but I couldn't come up with a better one.

I'm trying to lay out this website using purely CSS.  Previously this had been accomplished using javascript, but I know that it can be done with just CSS.

first off: here's a diagram of the intended layout:

[image: layout]
Basically, we have a wrapper page that has a header, a footer, and an iFrame:

wrapper.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="divHeader">
        </div>
        <div id="divMain" >
            <iframe id="ifrmMainBody" src="page.aspx"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="divFooter" >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

then, the page that is in the iFrame, uses a master page which has a main-menu, a navigation panel, a few more toolbars, and then the content:

main.master:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div id="mainMenu">
        main menu
    </div>
    <div id="navPanel">
        navigation panel
    </div>
    <div id="breadCrumb">
        bread crumb
    </div>
    <div id="caption">
        caption
    </div>
    <div id="subMenu">
        sub-menu
    </div>
    <div id="toolBar">
        toolbar
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</form>
```

And then there's the page that uses the master page.  I hard-coded in the width and height to force the scrollbars to appear:

page.aspx:

```
<form>
    <div style="height: 1200px; width: 1500px;">
        <p>
            Put content here.
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problems I'm facing are:

- Having problems getting the iFrame to take up the entire page height minus header and footer
- Getting the scrollbars to appear ONLY in the content section
- having the navigation panel and other toolbars not move when I scroll

Can anyone help me get this page laid-out correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think fixed position elements are kind of gross, because it forces the user to constantly see all your extra stuff when they might just want to see the content, but it sounds like what you're looking for.  You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HBeBq/

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 5em; // same as header height
    bottom: 5em; // same as footer height
    width: 10em;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}
#contentWrapper {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10em; // same as nav width
    top: 5em; // same as header height
    bottom: 5em; // same as footer height
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto; // if this div's contents are too big, scrollbars automatically appear
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, it's not how I would have chosen to lay the page out, but it's what's been assigned to me.  I actually just got it to work on my own using something really similar to what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Adam's answer is very good.  I did something similar:

```
/*in wrapper*/
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#divHeader
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #756398;
}
#divMain  /*container for iframe*/
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;    
}
#ifrmMainBody
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#divFooter
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #926531;    
}

/*in master*/
#mainMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #a9b77c;    
}
#navPanel
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 150px;  
    background-color: #b87c9a;  
}
#breadCrumb
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;  
}

#caption
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #AB79B8;  
}

#subMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #A7b2E5;  
}
#toolBar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #E76235;  
}
#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #666;
    overflow: auto;
}
```